# Wiring a 220 volt heater

Tags: electrical, wiring

So I’m wiring a 220 volt heater with no thermostat from 2 110 breakers. Using 20 amp dual pole breaker with 12 ga 3 wire. Going thru a 2 pole thermostat. I’ve wired my black and white to each breaker and green to my grounding strip on my breaker panel. Then I hooked the other end of the black and white wires to the “line” wires on my thermostat. I then wired the two load wires to each black wire on the heater. I’ve also wired the grounds together separately.
The heater will not come on.

Comment: So are you using the two breakers or a single double pole breaker?  If using two, make sure they are on different phases.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what wire is connected where - could you post photos of your breaker, thermostat and heater wiring connections?

Comment: Yes just one double breaker. Sorry I can’t do photo at the moment.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify.  You first said 2 110v breakers, then one 2 pole breaker with 12/3.   It makes a difference.  Like @JACK said, if 2 separate breakers they must be on opposite phases (legs).  BTW, if so, unless they are handle-tied, that's not a code legal approach.

Comment: How are you checking? By feel? Baseboards take annoyingly long to make enough heat to actually feel.  Try putting the thermostat to max and then coming back in 10 minutes.

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter? Check for 240V between the hot wires at the breaker, at the thermostat line terminals, at the thermostat load terminals, and at the heater. Note -- when testing the thermostat load terminals, turn the thermostat setting all the way up and all the way down. If the thermostat dial is poorly marked you may think it's at max when it's at min.

Comment: Thank you Jack! You were correct I have the wrong breaker box. Not configured for the phase needed. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Thanks to everyone else as well! Great to have a place to get answers. All of which were relevant in my situation.